# Inconsistency between OpenGL and CUDA maximum number of threads

Tags: opengl, cuda, gpgpu, compute-shader

My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GT440, whose compute capability version is 2.x. NVIDIA's official CUDA_C_Programming_Guide points out

> Limit 1. Maximum number of threads per block = 1024
>   Limit 2. Maximum number of resident threads per multiprocessor = 1536

However, two of the OpenGL computer shader implementation limits are

> Limit 3. GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS = 1536

My questions are
*1. Why Limit 1 is not equal to Limit 2 and Limit 3?

2. Should the real threads/block (invocations/workgroup) be 1024 or 1536?*

Comment: Isnt "2" a number of in-flight threads and dependent on hardware(so it may compute two blocks concurrently)?

Comment: The real threads per block is 1024 in CUDA.  It is a separate hardware limit from the 1536 number. A multiprocessor can have multiple blocks "resident" on it, so the multiprocessor can support more threads than just those emanating from a single block.  It seems evident that the GL limit may be connected to the Limit 2.  The difference between limit 1 and 2 is discussed in many questions here on SO as well as many places on the web if you care to look.

Comment: Maximum number of threads per block in CUDA is 1024. However, max compute work group invocations in OpenGL is 1536. They appear to be different. But I think CUDA **block** is the equivalent of OpenGL **Work Group**, and the two maximun value should be the same. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> Why Limit 1 is not equal to Limit 2 and Limit 3?

Because it isn't the same thing. Blocks are a logical construct in CUDA and are limited to a maximum of 1024 threads. But a multiprocessor can run multiple blocks concurrently (up to 8 in the case of your hardware). So a SM can have up to 1536 concurrent threads in your hardware, but not all of those threads can come from a single block.

> Should the real threads/block be 1024 or 1536?

1024 for all the reasons outlined above. You can see a complete summary of the capabilities of all supported hardware [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities).

Comment: I think CUDA **block** is the equivalent of OpenGL **Work Group**. Is it right?